# $\log x$ behaviour near $0$

Tags: logarithms

Apologize if the question sounds absurd, but what is the behavior of $\log x$ around $x=0$? I can see that it dominates $-\frac1x$, but what about for other negative powers of $x$, for instance $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: For any $a>0$, $x^a\log(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r>0$, then, by L'Hopital's rule,$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\log x}{-\frac1{x^r}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{-1}}{rx^{-r-1}}=\frac1r\lim_{x\to0^+}x^r=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality, I showed in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality

$$\log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}>-\frac1x\tag1$$

Since $a\log(x)=\log(x^a)>-\frac1{x^a}$, for any $a>0$ we have from $(1)$

$$\log(x)>-\frac1{ax^a}$$